# Using BeautifulSoup to extract specific nested div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML code which I'm creating the script for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFSPT.jpg
I would like to extract the highlighted text ("some text") and print it.
I tried going through every nested div in the way to the div I needed, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "the url this is from"
r = requests.get(url)

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"id": "main"}):
    for div2 in div.find_all("div", {"id": "app"}):
        for div3 in div2.find_all("div", {"id": "right-sidebar"}):
            for div4 in div3.find_all("div", {"id": "chat"}):
                for div5 in div4.find_all("div", {"id": "chat-messages"}):
                    for div6 in div5.find_all("div", {"class": "chat-message"}):
                        for div7 in div6.find_all("div", {"class": "chat-message-content selectable"}):
                            print(div7.text.strip())
```

I implemented what I've seen in guides and similar questions online, but I bet this is not even close and there must be a much easier way.
This doesn't work. It doesn't print anything, and I'm a bit lost. How can I print the highlighted line (which is essentially the very first div child of the div with the id "chat-messages")?

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div data-reactroot="" id="app">
            <div class="top-bar-authenticated" id="top-bar">
            </div>


            <div class="closed" id="navigation-bar">
            </div>


            <div id="right-sidebar">
                <div id="chat">
                    <div id="chat-head">
                    </div>


                    <div id="chat-title">
                    </div>


                    <div id="chat-messages">
                        <div class="chat-message">
                            <div class="chat-message-avatar" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/657dcec97cc00bc378629930ecae1776c0d981e0.jpg&quot;);">
                            </div>
                            <a class="chat-message-username clickable">
                            <div class="iron-color">
                                aloe
                            </div></a>

                            <div class="chat-message-content selectable">
                                <!-- react-text: 2532 -->some text<!-- /react-text -->
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>


                        <div class="chat-message">
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the html as text and not as image, it helps everyone trying to help!

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar You're right, doing it right now!

Answer (score 3):

Using `lxml` parser (i.e. `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')`) you can use `.find` with multiple classes just as simple as single classes to find nested divs:

```
soup.find('div',{'class':'chat-message-content selectable'}).text
```

The line above should work for you as long as the occurence of that class is the only one in the html.

Comment: This is not the only occurrence, since this class is in every class "chat-message". Do you know of any other solution, then?

Comment: I added the related HTML code. Every div with class "chat-message" has also the attribute class="chat-message-content selectable", so it's not the only occurrence. I've tried what you suggested but this didn't work.
Any idea what do I do?

Comment: "but this didn't work" - What happened, exactly? I runned the line of code with the above html and it returned me the expected output: `'\nsome text\n'`. 
"Every div with class "chat-message" has also the attribute class="chat-message-content selectable"" - That was not possible to see with the given example, if you have no specific characteristic to differentiate your desired tag from the other **at all**, then of course it's gonna be a hard time to do that.